# In Groovy, can you get a method reference to a local or statically imported method without restating the class?

Tags: groovy

Ideally I'd like to be able to express the idea: "whatever would be called by `foo()` in the current position in the code, give me a method reference to `foo`".

Rationale: I'm working on some code that uses a lot of high-order functions and function composition.  I'd like: a) it to be as terse as possible, and b) not to have to
keep editing class names scattered around the code as I refactor and move functions between classes.

For example:

```
/* ---- foo.pkg1.Utils.groovy */
public final class Utils {

    private Utils() { /* as it's all static methods */ }

    static foo() { 42; }

}

/* ---- foo.pkg2.Client1.groovy */
import foo.pkg1.Utils

def f1 = Utils.&foo // <-- restates class (but works)
println f1()

/* ---- foo.pkg2.Client2.groovy */
import static foo.pkg1.Utils.*

def f2 = foo  // <-- No!
// "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: foo ..."
println f2() 

def f3 = &foo  // <-- No!
// "unexpected token: & at line: 17, column: 14"
println f3()

def f4 = this.&foo  // <-- Also no!
// "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method..."
println f4()

/* ---- foo.pkg2.Client3.groovy */
/* My best attempt ... but this only allows me to change which
   class 'u' refers too, not to create a method reference to
   whatever `foo()` would call at the same place in the code. */
import static Utils as u

def f5 = u.&foo
println f5()
```

Answer (score 1):

Slightly error-prone due to variable naming being bounded to `with` order, but it is something:

```
    class Util {
        static foo(arg) { "foo $arg" }
        static bar() { "bar" }
        static batman(fn) { fn("captain") }
    }

    def (foo, bar, batman) = Util.with { [it.&foo, it.&bar, it.&batman] }

    assert foo("eck") == "foo eck"

    assert batman(foo) == "foo captain"
```

Handling the script's own `binding` using reflection on `Util` class is also an option if you always use scripts.

Comment: It seems that that would allow a few methods to be brought into the scope of a single client script or, interestingly, method.  They could then be called (or passed) without having to adorn them with `this`, their containing class, or a import alias for that class.  When used in a method and with `def` this would limit their scope to just that method, wouldn't it?  That seems potentially quite useful.

Comment: Yep, it would limit the scope to a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `MethodClosure` defined as a private static property of the class `Utils` like:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.MethodClosure

public final class Utils {
    private static final MethodClosure fooPointer = this.&foo
    private Utils() { }
    static foo() { 42 }
}

// Client
import static Utils.*
def f1 = fooPointer
println f1()
```

Do not know how will it be advantageous anyway.

Comment: Interesting, but no, that probably wouldn't help as it dissassociates the refence from the thing that it references (two different names - plus effort to maintain a pair of things for every library method).

Comment: I may be trying to go too much against the grain using Groovy this way.  But what I am trying to do it is program purely with functions (static methods, called only for their return values, no side-effects, their classes acting merely as namespaces hence non-instantiable).

Comment: What would be problem to statically import the class and just invoke `foo()` instead of `f1()` whenever deemed necessary?

Comment: That's exactly what I would do when I want do call the function (i.e. static method) directly.  But often I want to pass it to another function.  My `f*N*` `def`s above are to indicate that I want to be able to get a reference to the function (to hold on to, place in a data structure, pass as a parameter, return from a method, etc).